# About a possible other way to define the flat cover of a module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $M$ be an $R$-module. The flat cover of $M$ (which always exists) can be defined as a pair $(F, \phi)$ such that $\phi: F \to M$ is surjective, $F$ is a flat module, and every homomorphism from a flat module to $M$ factors through $F$. Moreover, any map from $F$ to itself that commutes with the map to $M$ is an automorphism of $F.

Okay, this is just the definition of a flat cover. The question is whether one can define a projective cover by simply replacing the last definition, replacing $F$ with $P$, where $P$ is a module in the class of all $R$-projective modules. It can be proven that this is equivalent in the case of a projective cover. In other words, "$(P, \phi)$" is a projective cover of an $R$-module if $\phi: P \to M$ is a superfluous epimorphism, meaning that for every $L \leq P$ such that $Ker(\phi) + L = P$, then $L = M$; in other words, $Ker(\phi)$ is superfluous in $P$.

A proof showing the equivalence of these two ways to define a projective cover can be found in "Flat covers" by Xu on page 15, as Theorem 1.2.12.

So, the question is, can we define a flat cover in a similar way? That is, can we say the following: $(F, \phi)$ is a flat cover of an $R$-module $M$ if $\phi: F \to M$ is a superfluous epimorphism and $F$ is a flat module? My intuition says no, but I find it strange that nobody uses this definition, although I cannot find a counterexample. I also have a hunch that this is not always true. Ideally, I would like to come across an example where $Ker(\phi)$ is not superfluous in $F$ while $F$ is flat. Thanks in advance for reading and for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative definition is not equivalent for noncommutative rings. (Although the question doesn't specify commutativity, it has the "commutative-algebra" tag, so possibly that's what the OP intended.)

The "superfluous" definition of covers is studied in

*Jain, S. K.; López-Permouth, Sergio R.; Rowen, Louis H.*, [**Superfluous covers**](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927879508825303), Commun. Algebra 23, No. 5, 1663-1677 (1995). [ZBL0829.16001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0829.16001).

([PDF available here.](https://people.ohio.edu/jain/039.pdf))

It's shown there that not every module has a flat cover in the "superfluous" sense, and so, since every module does have a flat cover in the usual sense, the two definitions must be nonequivalent.

However, it looks as though the argument in the paper necessarily needs a ring that is noncommutative. I don't know what happens for commutative rings, but I would guess the two definitions are still nonequivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much, Professor Rickard. Your answer is very insightful. If I understand correctly, the modules that would work as counterexamples are the autocovering modules, right? In other words, these are modules without a proper superfluous cover. Once again, thanks so much.

Comment: @Cos Yes, that's right. Or to be precise, the autocovering modules that are not themselves flat.